# Filter by post category in Media Library

Tags: categories, media, media-library

I am trying to find a way to filter the Media Library by the Post Category that a Media item is assigned with.  I can see that you can sort by "attached to" but this only get me a little of the way there.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` to filter the query.

So you can

1. retrieve a category from query vars
2. retrieve the post with that category
3. set the media query to include only posts having that post as the parent

To give a UI, you can use the `restrict_manage_posts` hook to output a category dropdown.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_filter_media_by_cat');
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'my_add_media_cat_dropdown' );

function my_filter_media_by_cat( $q ) {
  $scr = get_current_screen();
  $cat = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'postcat', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );   
  if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || ! is_admin() || (int)$cat <= 0 || $scr->base !== 'upload' )
      return;
  // get the posts
  $posts = get_posts( 'nopaging=1&category=' . $cat );
  // get post ids
  $pids = empty( $posts ) ? false : wp_list_pluck($posts, 'ID');
  if ( ! empty($pids) ) {
    $pidsTxt = implode( ',', $pids );
    global $wpdb;
    // Get the ids of media having retrieved posts as parent
    $mids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent IN ($pidsTxt)");
    if ( ! empty($mids) ) {
      // Force media query to retrieve only media having retrieved posts as parent
      $q->set( 'post__in', $mids );
    } else {
      // force media query to return no posts
      $q->set( 'p', -1 ); // Let query found nothing
    }
  }
}

function my_add_media_cat_dropdown() {
  $scr = get_current_screen();
  if ( $scr->base !== 'upload' ) return;
  $cat = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'postcat', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );   
  $selected = (int)$cat > 0 ? $cat : '-1';  
  $args = array(
      'show_option_none'   => 'All Post Categories',
      'name'               => 'postcat',
      'selected'           => $selected
  ); 
  wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
}
```

The negative of this code is that you have to run 3 queries to filter the media...

Result on UI:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I will check this out - looks like it is what I am looking for.  One question though - where is `postcat` coming from in the `my_add_media_cat_dropdown` function

Comment: `$cat = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'postcat', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );` is an alternate (better and safer) way of `$cat = $_GET['postcat'];`. See [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) @whodeee

Comment: thanks! Worked great!  Any suggestions for [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126800/admin-post-order-by-category-and-sub-category) I had?

Comment: @G.M. : `get_current_screen` only works on the backend but `pre_get_posts` runs front and back. You need an `is_admin` check.

Comment: gmazzap's solution inspired me to write a plugin to do this. You can now filter your media by Taxonomies and Terms with the [Media Library Filter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-filter/).

Comment: NOTE: $pidstxt = implode($pids, ','); to $pidstxt = implode( ',', $pids );

Comment: Thanks @Litalino fixed