# Media Library filter returns undefined function get_current_screen

Tags: categories, media-library

Hello I am following  [Filter by post category in Media Library](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126806/filter-by-post-category-in-media-library/126873#126873)

I copied the code answer into my functions.php file at the bottom and got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen()
```

Running Wordpress V3.7
Plugins that may conflict:
- Regenerate thumbs
- Unattach

Comment: Post _your_ code please. You are probably trying to use the function too early, by the way.

Comment: The code is from the linked page provided, there is no change? I am not able to comment on that post because I have too low rep ...  Thanks

Comment: There is what looks to me like an error in the logic of the code you are using as a model. See my comment on that answer.

Comment: This is a typical code for a plugin and not the theme. Also it is important, that the code run on admin area, like plugins_loaded or admin_init hook. If you add this source from the answer in the theme function, then you will problems and errors, is not validate in this context.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I will have a look.

Comment: @bueltge Okay I will look at other options for creating a media library category/page/post filter. Thanks :)